# Get control's size in design-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to get control's size dynamically even in design-time. If in runtime there is OnRender and other methods, but in design-time there is no such.

I need it to create correct DependencyProperty that will place another controls inside of parent dependent on parent's size. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you cannot do that, BTW I doubt why you need to do this?

Comment: For example I create a custom graphic container, and it has an "Items" DependencyProperty, so, I'd like to add it to my container automatically when Items property changed in XAML. Understand? :) But it's not a simple container, so items position and size dependent on container's SIZE.

Answer (score 2):

This is the responsibility of a `Panel`. A `Panel` has a collection of children and is responsible for measuring and arranging those children according to its layout rules. If none of the built-in panels are suitable for your purposes, you can always write your own.